# Guzzle Client Crawler Url Not found 404

Tags: laravel, web-crawler, guzzle, goutte, domcrawler

I'm url https://tiki.vn/sua-bot-meiji-noi-dia-hohoemi-milk-so-0-800g-p3678041.html

I use package https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

```html
$client = new Client();
    $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
      'verify' => false
  ));
  $client->setClient($guzzleClient);

    $res = $client->request('GET', $url);
    // Get text
echo $res->filter('h1')->text();
```

When i run code result 404 Not Found. I'm having this problem. Please help me

Comment: Are you sure that under variable $url you have proper (and working) url address?

Comment: url is working. https://tiki.vn/sua-bot-meiji-noi-dia-hohoemi-milk-so-0-800g-p3678041.html

Answer (score 0):

I has solved the problem

Set header `'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'`

```
$client->setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36');
```